# Solve the equation $x^{x+y}=y^{y-x}$ over natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Solve the equation $x^{x+y}=y^{y-x} \tag 1$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$

---

$x = 1,y = 1$ is a solution, now suppose $x \ne 1, y \ne 1$.

Obviously $x, y \ne 0$ and $x, y$ have same prime divisors.

Because $x+y \gt y-x$ it follows that $x \mid y$ therefore $y = kx$ and (1) becomes: $x^{(k+1)x}=(kx)^{(k-1)x} \tag2$ and, dividing by $x^{k-1}$ we get
$x^{2x}=k^{(k-1)x} \tag 3$ therefore $x^2=k^{k-1} \tag 4$ and here I've got stuck. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

From (4) we have $k \ge 3$ therefore $2 \le k-1$ and $ k \mid x$. Let $x=km$ and (4) becomes $k^2m^2=k^{k-1} \tag5$ and $m^2=k^{k-3} \tag6$

**UPDATE 2**

$x=t^{t^2-1}, y=t^{t^2+1}$ is solution $\forall t \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$

Comment: What does "$x,y$ have same prime divisors" mean exactly?

Comment: @ZainPatel I don't get your point

Answer (score 3):

$x^2 = k^{k-1}, k$ must be odd, or k is a perfect square.

k is odd.
$k = 2n+1\\
x,y = (2n+1)^n, (2n+1)^{n+1}$

$k$ is a pefect square. $k = n^2$

$x^2 = n^{2(2n-1)}\\
x,y = n^{2n-1}, n^{2n+1}$

Comment: Same idea as mine, more concisely.

Comment: $x=2^3, y=2^5$ is solution

Comment: @EugenCovaci: Yes! $k$ must be either odd, or a perfect square (so this answer is wrong).

Comment: @TonyK It's not wrong, just incomplete

Comment: @EugenCovaci: In my book, "$k$ must be odd" is wrong!

Comment: @TonyK Here you are right

Comment: I missed a case.  Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a simple Java program to attempt a bruceforce method:
(I understand this isn't always the best way to solve something like this, but it may help us find patterns)

Here are some solutions I have found:

In the form (x,y): **All the solutions between 1 and 1000**

- (1,1) (not an accepted solution)
- (3,9)
- (8,32)
- (25,125)

---

## Well, well, well...

1/1 = 1

9/3 = 3

32/8 = 4

125/25 = 5

- Do I see a pattern? :)

Answer (score 1):

From
$x^2=k^{k-1}$,
$k$ must be odd.
Let $k = 2j+1$,
so
$x^2 = (2j+1)^{2j}$
or
$x = (2j+1)^j$.

Then
$y = kx
=(2j+1)(2j+1)^j
= (2j+1)^{j+1}
$.

Check:

$x^{x+y}?y^{y-x}$

$\begin{array}\\
x^{x+y}
&=((2j+1)^j)^{(2j+1)^j+(2j+1)^{j+1}}\\
&=(2j+1)^{j(2j+1)^j(1+(2j+1))}\\
&=(2j+1)^{j(2j+1)^j(2j+2)}\\
&=(2j+1)^{2j(j+1)(2j+1)^j}\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
y^{y-x}
&=((2j+1)^{j+1})^{(2j+1)^{j+1}-(2j+1)^{j}}\\
&=(2j+1)^{(j+1)((2j+1)^{j+1}-(2j+1)^{j})}\\
&=(2j+1)^{(j+1)(2j+1)^{j}((2j+1)-1)}\\
&=(2j+1)^{(j+1)(2j+1)^{j}(2j)}\\
&=(2j+1)^{2j(j+1)(2j+1)^{j}}\\
\end{array}
$

And they match!

Comment: $x=2^3, y=2^5$ is also solution

Comment: Good point. I did not see the possibility that $k = m^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here the infinite family of all odd solutions.
$$x^{x+y}=y^{y-x}\iff(xy)^x=(\frac yx)^y\Rightarrow y=kx\\(kx^2)^x=k^{kx}\iff x^{2x}=k^{x(k-1)}\Rightarrow k-1=2n\\x^{2x}=k^{x(k-1)}\Rightarrow x^{2x}=(2n+1)^{2nx}\Rightarrow x=(2n+1)^n\Rightarrow\color{red}{ (x,y)=((2n+1)^n,(2n+1)^{n+1})}$$ This gives the following identity verifying the given equation
$$(2n+1)^{n(2n+1)^n(2n+2)}=(2n+1)^{(n+1)(2n+1)^n(2n)}$$
Something similar way, I guess, must gives the even solutions like $(x,y)=(8,32)$ if there are many of them.

Comment: Since you're assuming $x\ne0$, from $(kx^2)^x=k^{kx}$ you can deduce $kx^2=k^k$ or $x^2=k^{k-1}$. If $k$ is odd, then the solutions are as you showed. However $k$ might be an even perfect square, $k=h^2$, so the equation becomes $x=h^{2h-1}$ and *any* even $h$ is good.

Comment: So, we have found you and I all the solutions. This is pleasant is it not?. Regards.